# Setting up xampp and live reload with ssl port 35729

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, xampp, livereload

I am trying to set up grunt watch with livereload.js and XAMPP on Linux Mint.

The reason for this set up is it allows me to develop php/MySQL and maintain grunt functionality.

I have done this before on MAMP and a Mac all I had to do was in MAMP setting set SSL to 35729 and livereload worked with grunt watch.

However XAMPP does not have this setting and as such I have tried to manually edit the XAMPP ssl conf file (/opt/lampp/etc/extra/https-ssl.conf) by changing settings:

```
Listen 443 to Listen 35729
```

&

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443> to <VirtualHost _default_:35729>
```

However then if I use grunt watch I receive:

```
Fatal error: Port 35729 is already in use by another process.
```

I don't know what MAMP does differently but some how I need to emulate that functionality.

Any insight would be highly appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to let your Apache Webserver listen to grunts watch-port. Watch spans its own tiny webserver to deliver the update-javascript, you only have to include it in your website (manually or with the livereload browser extensions)

Dont know why you wanna do this?